# intl-tel-input is not adding country code with phone Number

Tags: javascript, jquery, intl-tel-input

I am using intl-tel-input plugin in my contact form. Plugin is running fine and dropdown is appearing well with all country codes and flags. but when i submit form, i can see only phone number i have added without any country code in start. here is what i am doing.

```
<input class="cfos_field" autocomplete="off" type="tel" name="number" id="cfos-number" placeholder="Your Number">
```

and here is my Jquery code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var rhInput = document.querySelector("#cfos-number");
        window.intlTelInput(rhInput, {
            initialCountry: "auto",
            geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
                jQuery.get('https://ipinfo.io', function () {
                }, "jsonp").always(function (resp) {
                    var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
                    callback(countryCode);
                });
            },
        });
    });
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong.